# I want to calculate time diff between starttime=23:30 and endtime=00:15 the time diff is coming -23.25

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate time diff:

```
start_time  = 23:30
Finish_time = 00:15
```

the time diff is coming -23.15 instead of 45 minutes.

my code:

```
DATEDIFF(minute, Start_Time, Finish_Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the data type is `Time`, Sql server can't know you mean the start time and end time is in a different day.
Here is one way to solve this:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Start_Time > Finish_Time THEN
            DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(Start_Time As datetime), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(Finish_Time As datetime)))
        ELSE
            DATEDIFF(minute, Start_Time, Finish_Time)
        END
FROM @T
```

If you want the result back as `time`, you can do this instead:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Start_Time > Finish_Time THEN
            CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(Finish_Time As datetime)) - CAST(Start_Time As datetime) as time)
        ELSE
            CAST(CAST(Finish_Time As datetime) - CAST(Start_Time As datetime) as time)
        END
FROM @T
```

[See live demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/CECDN12518)

Here is one way to get the values as decimal, where the right side of the decimal point is the hours and the left side is the minutes:

```
SELECT  CAST(
             REPLACE(
                     CONVERT (char(5), 
                              CASE WHEN Start_Time > Finish_Time THEN
                                CAST(DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(Finish_Time As datetime)) - CAST(Start_Time As datetime) as time)
                              ELSE
                                CAST(CAST(Finish_Time As datetime) - CAST(Start_Time As datetime) as time)
                              END
                     , 114)
             , ':', '.')
        as decimal(4,2))
FROM @T
```

Last edit:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  CASE WHEN Start_Time > Finish_Time THEN
                DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(Start_Time As datetime), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(Finish_Time As datetime)))
            ELSE
                DATEDIFF(minute, Start_Time, Finish_Time)
            END As DiffInMinutes
    FROM @T
)
SELECT ((DiffInMinutes - (DiffInMinutes % 60)) / 60) + CAST((DiffInMinutes % 60) as float) / 60 As DiffAsDecimalHours
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks Johar for your help. I am using the first way to solve my issue. But it shows values as integer. I am trying to convert this column in float with two decimal places but giving some error. Could you please advise me how to convert this into float with two decimal places. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you want the result to be `00.45`? You do realize that's not the same as `00:45`, right?

Comment: @DineshGuleria - storing "decimal time" almost always comes back to bite people - usually after they've already done something inappropriate (such as adding two such values together) and expect to somehow be able to magically fix it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I totally agree, hence my comment before the edit.

Comment: HI Zohar! Thanks for your prompt response. I want to convert the data from Chargeabe_Time column in hours. So as it is like 04:30:00 but I want to see this as 4.5 hours. Thank you very much if can help me to change this column

Comment: Or using the first code,                                                                  SELECT  CASE WHEN Start_Time > Finish_Time THEN
            DATEDIFF(minute, CAST(Start_Time As datetime), DATEADD(DAY, 1, CAST(Finish_Time As datetime)))
        ELSE         DATEDIFF(minute, Start_Time, Finish_Time)
        END
FROM @T    I am getting time in minutes but I want to see this is hours (two decimal places) as my price is in hours. Thanks and sorry for disturbing you again and again. Let me tell you, I am new to SQL Server